# How can I create "n" number of arbitrary Actors to do concurrent processing?

Tags: concurrency, akka

I am very new to Akka (just started looking today) and believe I have a need to create a program using Akka that reads messages from Kafka. Say for example my message looks like "{weather: Rainy, zipcode: 123456, temperature: 55 }". I would like to route each message as it comes in based on specific Zipcode to an Actor that handles messages related to that zipcode.

I guess I have 2 problems here.
1) At the start of my application, I'm not sure what number of Actors I will need.

2) How to specify that an Actor belongs to a specific zipcode and route the messages there?

3-ish) Is this something I can use Akka + Kafka for? Or something more suited towards streaming like Alpakka?

Answer (score 1):

1. not a problem given the answer to 2
2. have a look at cluster sharding: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/cluster-sharding.html
3. really depends on what you exactly need, you could also use pure kafka stream.

If you need to scale out (i.e., have more than can fit inside a single JVM given the volume/throughput requirements), then you should consider either cluster sharding or pure kafka streams. Which one is another question.